# Import SQL tables as data into access Db

Tags: sql-server, vba, odbc, ms-access-2010

I have a SQL database (lets use northwind), that has a number of tables (unknown number of tables). I would like to import these tables into a MS access database as DATA (not tables) into a MTT_Table

All standard imports, creates the table as a physical table within ms access and not as data.
I have a table in MS Access that needs to store all the names of tables in other systems - not sure if that makes sense

Is there any way to read an infinite number of tables and populate them as data, using an odbc connection all through VBA

Expected output would be to see the table names as data values, and potentially able to populate the MS access row with metadata about the table

Comment: https://www.quackit.com/microsoft_access/microsoft_access_2016/howto/how_to_import_a_sql_server_database_into_access_2016.cfm

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this imports and creates physical table in MS access. I am looking at loading the tables that are in sql as data into a table called MTT_Table in access. I have an ms access database that needs to store all table names - not sure if that makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use information schema to create a view in SQL server:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Sample_View
AS
   SELECT TABLE_NAME 
   FROM [Your_Database].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
   WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Now import this view to access following the steps in this [link](https://www.quackit.com/microsoft_access/microsoft_access_2016/howto/how_to_import_a_sql_server_database_into_access_2016.cfm)

Comment: Thank you, will try this. Is there any other way to do it without creating a view? Reason that I am asking is I could potentially have to import 300 systems worth of tables, and not all of them will be in SQL, am testing the logic in access and sql, but ultimately the storage system will be a sql database, that needs to connect via odbc and extract this from other systems

Comment: @Jext You should give a try to Erik A's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit broad (*what* information do you want from tables), but generally can be achieved by querying the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` meta-tables over ODBC.

```
SELECT * INTO MTT_Table
FROM [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=my\server;Database=myDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```